# Nodejs how to replace /\/[^\/]+\.domain\.com/ to exp.domain.com

Tags: node.js, replace

In php

```
preg_replace("/\/[^\/]+\.mýite\.com/","/sub.mysite.com", str);
```

But in node js i cant replace. Plz help me. thank!

```
var link = link.replace(/\/[^\/]+\.mýite\.com/gi, "/sub.mysite.com");
```

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: Then edit your question with the code you tried so that others can help you.

Comment: Your code in Node, what is it?

Comment: var link = link.replace(/\/[^\/]+\.mýite\.com/gi, "/sub.mysite.com");

Comment: i update it . . .

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: url string it not replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work, but if you have file encoding issues, you can do:

#### Code:

```
var link = link.replace(/\/[^\/]+\.m.ite\.com/gi, "/sub.mysite.com")
```

#### My Output:

```
> "http://exp.mýite\.com".replace(/\/[^\/]+\.m.ite\.com/gi, "/sub.mysite.com");
"http://sub.mysite.com"
```